# Python Surprise package gives different predictions for predict method vs manual compute using latent factors

Tags: python-3.x, svd, recommendation-engine, matrix-factorization

I am using the surprise package for matrix factorization. Below is the code for the tutorial:

```
from surprise import SVD
from surprise import Dataset
from surprise import accuracy
from surprise.model_selection import train_test_split

# Load the movielens-100k dataset (download it if needed),
data = Dataset.load_builtin('ml-100k')
trainset = data.build_full_trainset()

algo = SVD()
algo.fit(trainset)

algo.predict(str(196), str(302))

Out:
Prediction(uid='196', iid='301', r_ui=4, est=3.0740854315737174, details={'was_impossible': False})
```

However, when I use the SVD equation from its [documentation](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/matrix_factorization.html#surprise.prediction_algorithms.matrix_factorization.SVD) and [source code](https://github.com/NicolasHug/Surprise/blob/fa7455880192383f01475162b4cbd310d91d29ca/surprise/prediction_algorithms/matrix_factorization.pyx) to manually compute the r_hat (r prediction):

```
algo.trainset.global_mean + algo.bi[301] + algo.bu[196] + np.dot(algo.qi[301], algo.pu[196]) 

Out:
2.817335384596893
```

The predictions does not match at all. Am I doing anything wrong or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. There's a difference between `raw users/items` and `inner users/items`. The former refers to the actual names of the users and items (e.g., user = John or a number like 10; items = Avengers or a number like 20) while the latter I assume to be the label encoded values given to the original users/items.

The hidden attributes of the trainset contain 4 attributes, `_inner2raw_id_items`, `_inner2raw_id_users`, `_raw2inner_id_items`, `_raw2inner_id_users`, which are dicts containing the conversion from one to the other.

If we call `trainset._raw2inner_id_users` and `trainset._raw2inner_id_items`, we get:

```
_raw2inner_id_users
{'196': 0,
 '186': 1,
 '22': 2, ...}

_raw2inner_id_items
{'242': 0,
 '302': 1,
 '377': 2, ... 
 '301': 404, ...}
```

Therefore, when we call:

```
algo.predict(str(196), str(302))

Out:
# different from original post as the prediction changes from run to run
Prediction(uid='196', iid='301', r_ui=None, est=3.2072618383879736, details={'was_impossible': False})
```

We are actually referring to the 0<sup>th</sup> user and 1<sup>st</sup> item. So when we use the manual computation using the latent factors, bias, and global mean according to the SVD equation, we should use these numbers instead:

```
algo.trainset.global_mean + algo.bi[404] + algo.bu[0] + np.dot(algo.qi[404], algo.pu[0]) 

Output:
3.2072618383879736
```